# Looking for "On save feature for Outlook add-ins"

Tags: office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

Looking for "On save feature for Outlook add-ins"

On the Microsoft document, I've got the On to send add-ins event (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/outlook-on-send-addins) which is used when we create a new event.
Similarly when we update the event the "Send" button changes to "Save", however, the same "Save" event documentations is not present on the Microsoft document.

How can I call my custom function when a user clicks on save while updating any event and update the same on my custom code.

Comment: Are you creating appointment for yourself? Can you share repro step where "Send" changes to "Save"? And which platform (OWA, desktop, iOS, Android) you are using?

Comment: Yes, I am creating an appointment, When we create a new event there is always a "Save" button, but when we select attendees name it changes to "Send" which is working fine using "On send feature for Outlook add-ins".

Now, When I update the same appointment, the button always statys "Save" for which I'm not able to call the custom function on "Save" button.

I'm using OWA

please check below screencast for more information.
https://www.hippovideo.io/video/play/fOCjf98CNtQ1TjRP61q-XN77p_E3KSd5uRhh9jfyKHQ

Comment: Currently the onSave feature for outlook add-ins is not supported. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our [user-voice page](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins). Please add your request there. Feature requests on user-voice are considered when we go through our planning process.

Comment: Thanks @Outlook Add-ins Team - MSFT for reply. 
I'll add my request on user-voice.